# Use LiipImagineBundle without filters

Tags: symfony, liipimaginebundle

I'm using [LiipImagineBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/LiipImagineBundle/index.html) in my Symfony2 project and everything is working great. I've defined a thumbnail filter:

```
<img src="{{ 'bundles/app/images/home/warning.jpg'|imagine_filter('thumb_home') }}" alt="Warning" />
```

And it works perfectly, but some of my images don't need any filter, so I've tried to remove the filter:

```
<img src="{{ 'bundles/app/images/home/warning.jpg'|imagine_filter('') }}" alt="Warning" />
<img src="{{ 'bundles/app/images/home/warning.jpg'|imagine_filter() }}" alt="Warning" />
```

***edited to correct the example as malcolm points out*

But it doesn't work, so I need to use [Assetic](http://symfony.com/doc/current/assetic.html) for these images:

```
{% image '@AppBundle/Resources/public/images/example.jpg' %}
  <img src="{{ asset_url }}" alt="Example" />
{% endimage %}
```

I can't find in the documentation of the bundle any option which allows me to use the Bundle without filters. Is that true? Of course, I can use the LiipImagineBundle way to include images when they need a filter and the Assetic way when they don't, but switching between two different ways of achieving almost the same thing is pretty annoying.

Comment: If you don't include `imagine_filter()` you don't use the bundle, the problem you have it's not related to imagine bundle.

Comment: Do you mean `{{ 'bundles/app/images/home/warning.jpg' | imagine_filter() }}`? That doesn't work. `Warning: Missing argument 2 for Liip\ImagineBundle\Templating\ImagineExtension::filter()`

Comment: No, I mean that in yours second example you don't use imagine bundle, that's why the question is not related to that bundle, and bundle works as expected.

Comment: Ohh, yes, that's right. It's a stupid example. Anyway, my question is if there is a way to use de bundle without filters, so obviously it _is_ related to the bundle.

Comment: The bundle is for image filters not for assetic functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Silly answer to your question - create an `original` size filter then :). Something like this:

```
class OriginalSizeFilter implements LoaderInterface
{
    public function load(ImageInterface $image, array $options = [])
    {
        $size = $image->getSize();
        $origWidth = $size->getWidth();
        $origHeight = $size->getHeight();

        $filter = new Thumbnail(new Box($origWidth, $origHeight));
        $image = $filter->apply($image);

        return $image;
    }
}
```

service:

```
original_size_filter:
    class: ...\OriginalSizeFilter
    tags:
        - { name: liip_imagine.filter.loader, loader: original_size_filter }
```

config.yml:

```
filter_sets:
    original:
        filters:
            original_size_filter: ~
```

Usage:

```
<img src="{{ 'bundles/app/images/home/warning.jpg'|imagine_filter('original') }}" alt="Warning" />
```

**But, why not use a `asset()` function if you don't want any filters to be applied?**